# Handling WCF methods with single request format

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to implement a WCF service where all the operations should be perform with a single request. That means the .svc will contain only single method and I need to filter parameter(somehow) to identify the operation need to perform.

For more understanding:
I one class library where I have implemented different classes for methods.
Now, I need to use that methods in my service but with only one method.

Can somebody please suggest me the best way to achieve this?

Advanced thanks.

Comment: You could look at Document Style which would achieve this. The "traditional" way with WCF is RPC. Just Google the differences / approaches etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement something like this:

```
ServiceResponse CallService(ServiceRequest theRequest)
```

Where `ServiceResponse` and `ServiceRequest` are objects that exist in the WCF space to handle the parameters needed and tell you which method to run.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @landoncz. I was planning to follow the same. but how I will manage the parameters of the methods as all methods are having different number of parameters?

Comment: If these are simple parameters, you can structure your ServiceRequest object in such a way that it contains a Parameters property that is a string[], or other object of your choice

Comment: When I am running my service on test client, It shows "The operation is not supported in the WCF Test Client because it uses type ServiceRequest". Can you please figure it out?